# Как вычисляют VPN?

Tags: vpn

Скажите, как вычисляют пользователей, которые используют VPN? Например, сайт Netflix борется с просмотрщиками видео из других стран баня целые VPN-сервисы.. Как им это удаётся?

Answer (score 2):

Элементарно! У каждого VPN-сервиса есть подсеть из "белых" IP-адресов. Найти эту подсеть для конкретного VPN-сервиса несложно. А далее просто баним подсеть целиком. Profit!

Comment: а есть какой-то выход из таких ситуаций? к примеру, создать vpn на каком-то хостинге только лишь для себя и нигде его не палить, тогда смогут вычислить?

Comment: @KonstantinVolobuev Зависит от того, как вычисляют. Если IP - единственный критерий, то нет. Но если заморочатся и будут проверять досконально, то смогут. Трафик через VPN немного отличается от обычного, да и язык системы можно учитывать.

Comment: и ещё такое уточнение.. есть допустим некий хостинг, на котором можно разместить индивидуальный vpn, могут ли взять этот хостинг и полностью забанить? Или это чревато баном не только vpn-щиков?

Comment: @KonstantinVolobuev Вряд ли будут банить целиком хостинг. Да и, скорее всего, банить будут групповые VPN, а от одного человека убыток маленький и на него вряд ли обратят внимание.